# Passing a function argument to ddply

Tags: r, function, plyr

I know there are various similar questions out there and as such I aplogize for the repetition. That said, while I have found useful information on this topic, nothing I've attempted seems to work.

In short, I'm using ddply inside a function, and attempting to pass an argument from the function to a function in ddply.

A simplified example using the `iris` dataset

```
IG_test <-function(data, feature){
  dd<-ddply(data, feature, here(summarise), N=length(feature))
  return(dd)
}

IG_test(iris, "Species")
```

This should return the number of records for every Species, but rather returns 1 in each case.

If I specify "Species" directly in `length()`, I get what I'm looking for

```
IG_test <-function(data, feature){
  dd<-ddply(data, feature, here(summarise), N=length(Species))
  return(dd)
}

    IG_test(iris, "Species")

     Species  N
1     setosa 50
2 versicolor 50
3  virginica 50
```

The most recent questions describing similar problems suggest using `here()` for the `summarize()` function in ddply, in order to tell ddply where to look for the variable. this works insomuch as `feature` is found (without `here()` we get an error), however it doesn't return the length as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passign a string name "Species" to a ddply function. So you should get it's value inside. Then ddply recognize column name

```
library(plyr)
IG_test <-function(data, feature){
  dd<-ddply(data, feature, here(summarise), N=length(get(feature)))
  return(dd)
}

IG_test(iris, "Species")
```